# Ember Force Route to Refresh Page

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

In my application I need to have certain sections of my app hard refresh on transition. I have gotten pretty close by creating another `Location` type I call
`passthrough` and then separating out the routes into a separate file. The `passthrough` location option essentially attempts to replace any where that history state was previously pushed and instead just `location.href =` the new `pathname`. The problem I am having now is that while this more or less works the router has already triggered a run loop and the view is rendered for a split second before it is refreshed. Not super familiar with how to control the run loop so thought maybe someone could help.

`/location/passthrough.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

/* Implement history API that hard refreshes on transition */
export default Ember.Object.extend({
  implementation: 'passthrough',
  rootURL: '/',

  init() {
      this.set('location', this.get('location') || window.location);
      this.set('baseURL', Ember.$('base').attr('href') || '');
  },

  setURL(path) {
    this.get('location').href = path;
  },

  replaceURL(path) {
    this.get('location').href = path;
  },

  getURL() {
    var rootURL = this.get('rootURL');
    var location = this.get('location');
    var path = location.pathname;
    var baseURL = this.get('baseURL');

    rootURL = rootURL.replace(/\/$/, '');
    baseURL = baseURL.replace(/\/$/, '');

    var url = path.replace(baseURL, '').replace(rootURL, '');
    var search = location.search || '';

    url += search;
    url += this.getHash();

    return url;
  },

  onUpdateURL() {
    if (this.get('location').pathname === this.getURL()) {
      return;
    }

    window.location.href = this.getURL();
  },

  formatURL(url) {
    return url;
  },

  getHash: Ember.Location._getHash
});
```

`/initializers/location.js`

```
import PassThroughLocation from '../location/passthrough';

export function initialize(instance) {
  instance.register('location:passthrough', PassThroughLocation);
}

export default {
  name: 'location',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Then in my router I have `location:'passthrough'` set.

Part of my reasoning to do this is for certain pages I want to include additional modules and set separate CSP. Basically when you hit `/secure/path` the server side sets a stricter CSP in the headers and loads a handful of modules only used in this section of the website.

UPDATE:

Overriding the behavior of a `link-to` component seems possible although pretty intimate.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export function initialize() {
    Ember.LinkComponent.reopen({
        _invoke: function (event) {
            window.location.href = event.target.pathname;

            return false;
        }
    });
}

export default {
  name: 'location',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

Comment: Why do you need to refresh you page in an ember app? It doesn't seem very emberish.

Comment: Is this what you want ? On reaching certain child routes, You need one or more of its parent route's model to be refreshed from server.

Comment: @caffinatedmonkey it definitely is not emberish but your comment is pretty much just noise its still a problem I need to solve for. AcidBurn yes basically I want certain routes to hit the backend server before rendering. Want to keep my front end code base in the same framework

Comment: Actually caffinatedmonkey is right on the money. What you should be doing is refreshing the model within the Route and possibly resetting controller state. The noise is in your head...

Comment: @ChristopherMilne how would I be able to change my CSP on the fly in a situation like that

Comment: @BillPull can you post some code or describe your situation in detail? There are potentially many ways to handle this.

Comment: @ChristopherMilne other than the code in the post there is just some backend code that sets the CSP headers depending on which route you hit.

Comment: is it an option for you to authenticate via an api client-side? failing that, to do what you originally requested, is it an option for you to replace link-to helpers with actual anchor tags (binding the href attribute)? that would give you the behaviour you are looking for without all the history manipulation

Comment: @ChristopherMilne would it be possible to alter the way `link-to` works? I think rather than replace all of the helpers & their functionality on the other pages it could be possible to load and insert a new link-to implementation

Comment: On reaching any child route, The `didTransition` hook of each parent route also gets triggered. Use some logic there to update the model. You need not refresh the page.